why does only one side get to argue?
Once again, in this thread:
Is it reasonable to view religions as theories, and, if so, to examine their theoretical predictions in order to test them empirically?
my answer gets attacked with irrelevant asides by people who fear that I don't support their religious or political prejudices sufficiently, and when I answer those attacks, my answers get deleted while the attacks are allowed to remain. I'm fine if you want to delete arguments, but it is unethical to delete only one side of the argument, leaving the impression to readers that the points made by that side cannot be answered.

(I'm not the mod who has been active on that thread, so I'll let him decide what to do about the remaining comments.) I do see that in many of your deleted comments you personally attack the person you're speaking with. Also the whole discussion of Trump and US politics is off topic for the site and probably should be avoided in your answer as well.

@causative I'm finding comments getting arbitrarily, thread-breakingly deleted even here on meta. This is like having a congressional hearing on right to free speech and gagging the ones who threaten to expose the govt that is doing the gagging!! Usually when incendiary comments are present, there's almost always a buildup. So it's almost always wrong to selectively delete only flagged comments. More so if the flag was raised by one side if the flareup

@Rushi There has been some excessive flagging recently. Re selective deletion of "incendiary comments," the discussion about Trump just doesn't belong here so it was right to delete the whole thing. But generally speaking, the one who makes the first personal attack is giving up the high ground. That's where the line is in my view. Attack the argument, not the person. That includes calling them uninformed; instead, inform them. (And do avoid using excessively derisive language about the argument, too, but also keep your cool or just leave if the other person doesn't return the courtesy)

@causative, the one who made the first personal attack in that thread was the one who said I deserved to be ostracized for being all of the things I was accused of. This person has personally attacked me many times on this site.

@DavidGudeman Well, if so, that person should not have done that and you should stop engaging once that happens, and certainly shouldn't insult back. A fruitful exchange of views requires a minimum level of willingness on both sides to give a fair hearing to what the other person has to say. Personal attacks are a clear sign that the other person does not have that willingness, and it's time to stop.

@NotThatGuy That particular quote doesn't seem to be a personal attack because you're speaking of a hypothetical situation in which someone loses friends or is fired for being bigoted or rude. You aren't saying this happened to David specifically. However, I see several people in that discussion did make personal attacks, including you.

@causative Indeed, that was intended as a general statement, referring to the general "you" (as David's comment does as well, although their subsequent response was... definitely not a general statement). And I agree that a lot of those comments, including mine, weren't all that appropriate as comments, and I don't object to them being moved to chat / removed, as they were.

Don't worry; your answer stands for itself
I never assume "points made" by one side in comments can't be answered. It is normal and reasonable for comments to go ignored by an answer author if they see no value to addressing them. That approach is actually better than to engage further debate; further debate would be inconsistent with the purpose of comments on StackExchange. You don't need to change their mind or even correct them. What matters is that your position is clear in your answer. If your position is clear and correct, it doesn't matter that someone else says something incorrect in a comment.
You say in the comments

It's easy to win an argument if the other side isn't allowed to disagree with you.

But that's just not how arguments or your answer are evaluated. You know that non-response is not at all indicative of the strength of the other side.
Cleaning up comments
Regarding the circumstance where only a portion of comments are deleted, it is generally because moderators respond to flags. It takes extra work for a moderator to review all the surrounding non-flagged comments. You can flag stragglers to clean things up.

As you yourself have argued ( here and elsewhere), there are often valuable comments. So yes the SE format ideally should be almost exvlusively a question-answer one. But it's a pipe dream for phil-SE.
